# meaning of "ride out to"

Tags: meaning

> “On my first trip to Italy, I found myself in Rome in heavy traffic,
>   **riding out to** the highway that leads to Florence. We were driving
>   during the rush hour in winter, and so the sun was setting, and the
>   unique pastel colors of the eternal city made the old buildings come
>   alive in the warming light.”
>
> From "The Re-Enchantment of Everyday Life" by Thomas Moore

How to interpret "riding out to" here?

A person is either driving a car or riding in a car. Does "**riding**" here imply that the writer himself was not driving the car? Because the following sentence tells us that they were driving during the rush hour, I guess the writer’s family was driving the car. But I am not sure.

Does "**out**" imply that they were going to a remote place or does it simply mean out of traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be overthinking this.  The author seems just to want to avoid using the word "driving" repeatedly, so he uses the synonym "riding". But that is a stylistic choice rather than a grammatical requirement. It doesn't seem to imply anything very special.

It is also possible, looking only at the short extract, that the author is riding/driving a motorbike.

"Out" seems just to mean "out of the city centre", as the Florence highway (the E45) passes to the East of the city.